# Xamarin Forms ToolbarItem different sizing in android and ios

Tags: xamarin.forms

currently in my project im using Xamarin forms and im using ToolBarItem as part of my app headers

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="Archive.png" Command="{Binding ArchiveCommand}" />
        <ToolbarItem Command="{Binding InboxCommand}" IconImageSource="Inbox_black.png"/>
        <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="plus.png" Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}"/>
        <ToolbarItem IconImageSource ="Logout.png" Command="{Binding LogoutCommand}" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

however, it appears different on ios and android. ive attached images below to show the difference, Android on the left, ios on the right.

[image][image]

what setting do i need to change in my code or Visual Studio for Mac to set them the same

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="Admin" FontSize="Large" TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
            <ImageButton Source="Archive.png" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="End" Command="{Binding ArchiveCommand}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
                <Label Padding="5,0 "/>
            <ImageButton Source="Inbox_black.png" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="End" Command="{Binding InboxCommand}" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
                <Label Padding="5,0 "/>
            <ImageButton Source="plus.png" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="End" Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
                <Label Padding="5,0 "/>
            <ImageButton Source="Logout.png" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="End" Command="{Binding LogoutCommand}" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
                <Label Padding="5,0 "/>
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

Thanks to Bassies for providing a hint to solve the problem. I changed the ToolBarItems section to a stacklayout nested inside TitleView which gives me more options to customise the UI to how i want it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the icons a Widht and Height .Something like this.

```
    <ImageButton Source="close.png" WidthRequest="60" HeightRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
```

Comment: Glad that you get it to work , can you put the question on Solved